# Markdown links to StackExchange sites and special actions

Tags: support, markdown

Markdown supports special links to the StackExchange sites, such as `[vi.se]` to "Vi & Vim" or `[unix.se]` to "Unix & Linux."

Do these only work in comments? Or in other contexts too? (They didn't seem to work in asking this question here on Meta, at least from what Preview was showing me.)

Where can I find a list of the special site Markdown links for all sites in the StackExchange network?

There are also some other special links such as `[edit]` to link to the form that will edit the question. Are there other special links such as that one?

Comment: Thanks, yeah that helps! It would probably be great to include that somewhere in [help]... 